Short sci-fi novel in which aliens mutated humans by showing them some image
Please help me find a short sci-fi novel I read about 40 years ago:

There were incoming aliens and humans were mutating from just looking at them (or some other image?).
Humans found a blind Special Forces operator who shot the aliens.
But they mutated him by playing a sound.
But he realized that in time and killed himself quickly.

The shooter successfully killed all but one alien who remained silent for a short moment, then the shooter heard the last alien flick some switch, so he managed to kill him (it?), too. But that switch turned on a sound that started to mutate the shooter slowly. He realized he's being mutated because his vision started to return, and so he shot himself.
Claude thinks "Based on your description, it sounds like you might be referring to the short story "Blindfold" by Kevin O'Donnell Jr. This story was published in 1974 in the anthology "Universe 4," edited by Terry Carr.", but there's nothing like that in Universe 4.

To save old and slow people like myself a moment of consternation, the "Claude" dude mentioned in the post is probably Anthropic's AI assistant of the same name.

@EikePierstorff - Hence the answer is a complete nonsense

@Valorum the really weird thing is, if I search for ""Blindfold" by Kevin O'Donnell Jr. " on Google, I get an excerpt for an Amazon review of Blindfold ("Blindfold reads more like a fantasy novel with feudal infighting, intrique and conspiracies"), even though the link points to  O'Donnell's existing novel "Bandersnatch". I assume Amazon uses articifial intelligence as well for SEO purposes.

Just remembered another detail - the shooter successfully killed all but one alien who remained silent for a short moment, then the shooter heard the last alien flick some switch, so he managed to kill him (it?), too. But that switch turned on a sound that started to mutate the shooter slowly. He realized he's being mutated because his vision started to return, and so he shot himself

I'm tempted to remove the AI-generated garbage.  There's no story by O'Donnell in Universe 4 (his first story was 1973, and his second was 1975), there's no story with a matching plot in Universe 4, there's no story by O'Donnell with that name, or any story with "Blind" in the title in any of the Universe {N} collections, the first story titled "Blindfold" was released in 2000...

@DavidW there is a novel "Blindfold" by Kevin Anderson from 1995, which is the one mentioned in my other comment. The AI garbage was trained on the Search Engine garbage, presumably. I think it would be a good idea if you gave in to temptation ;-)
